# Declare a js variable which will be accessed my 2 jsps

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have a requirement in which I have to assign a value to a variable which should be accessed by another jsp which will be called from that jsp.
Elaboration :

I have an html field, which is a dropdown whose list values are always constant.
The significance of it is, another field is dependent on it.

So from a page if the value is selected, it goes to a different jsp(via action).
I want the dropdown selection to persist in the next page.
Please suggest anythig.

Comment: Why can't you just submit the selection in the post back and then set the value in the second JSP on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to pass the selected value in URL and get it from `request.getParameter` another way to write it in `cookie if its not security issue`. It's up to you how do you want ?Please refer below post for more session tracking ways.

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html

Answer (score 2):

You can store the data into a  `JavaBean` with scope `request`. From the first jsp you can create the Bean and set all its properties, which correspond to the form fields names, with an istruction like

```
<jsp:setProperty name="beanName" property="*" />
```

which automatically tries to set all (not-empty) request parameters.

In the second jsp which is the one that receive the form data, you can read from the Bean the properties that you want with

```
<jsp:getProperty name="beanName" property="propertyName" />
```

You can also `forward` from the first jsp to the second, and the Bean will still store the data for you.